# MovieWriter imagemagick unavailable

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, imagemagick, python-visual

I am trying to animate the graph, but jupyter is giving error:

MovieWriter imagemagick unavailable.
And just animating the 1st image(which is obvious as MovieWriter is not working). How to fix it?

Python version: 3

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# number of nodes
size = 10

# generate graph
G=nx.complete_graph(size)

frame = np.random.randint(0, 5, (size, size)) # random ndarray between 0 and 5, length and number of frames = number of nodes in the graph

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos)
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
plt.axis('off')

def update(i):
    nc = frame[i] # np.random.randint(2, size=200)
    nodes.set_array(nc)
    return nodes,

# output animation; its important I save it
fig = plt.gcf()
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=50, frames=range(size), blit=True)
ani.save('crap.gif', writer='imagemagick',  savefig_kwargs={'facecolor':'white'}, fps=1)
```

Expectation: Animation should be working and will be able to show the updated color

Comment: matplotlib requires some tool to display/write images. In this case it is looking for ImageMagick. If you do not have it installed, then you will need to install it. Alternately, I believe that matplotlib can use other display tools. But you will need to look at its list of display tools from its documentation. Your`ani.save` is specifically asking for ImageMagick as its image writer.

Answer (score 2):

It is working after installing the `networkx` package and adding `pillowwritter` as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter
```

[networkx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4PWH.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please remember to follow the formatting conventions